# Bronto PHP API to get subscription status to a specific list for a specific email

Tags: php, api, bronto

I am trying to figure out how to using PHP and the Bronto API to identify if a user is subscribed or unsubscribed to a specific email list.

I am using the below code and my issue is that regardless if the user is subscribed or unsubscribed I always get a status of "active" for the user and what I need to see is not if they are on the list but unsubscribed or on the list and subscribed.

Anyway know what I should change?

```
 <?php
     $client = new SoapClient('https://api.bronto.com/v4?wsdl', array('trace' => 1, 
                             'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS));

    try {
          //token
          $token = "abc 123 and yz";

          //print "logging in\n";
          $sessionId = $client->login(array('apiToken' => $token))->return;

           $session_header = new SoapHeader("http://api.bronto.com/v4",
               'sessionHeader',
               array('sessionId' => $sessionId));
           $client->__setSoapHeaders(array($session_header));

            // set up a filter to read contacts and match on email address
            $filter = array('email' => array(array('operator' => 'EqualTo',
                   'value' => 'fake.person@gmail.com'
                   ),
               ),
      ); 
            $contacts = $client->readContacts(array('pageNumber' => 1,
                  'includeLists' => false,
                  'filter' => $filter,
                  )
                )->return;

            // print matching contact email addresses
             foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
             //$contact->status  always seems to have a status of active or null ??
              if($contact->status ='subscribed')
             {
                echo " <a href='' class='btn btn-primary'>Unsubscribe</a>";
             }
              else if($contact->status ='Unsubscribed')
             {
               echo " <a href=''>Subscribe</a>";
             }
               //print $contact->email . ': ' . $contact->status . "\n";
            }

          } catch (Exception $e) {
            print "uncaught exception\n";
            print_r($e);
        }
```

Comment: You should really indent your code properly so it's easier to follow the flow of it.

Comment: From your question, it sounds like [readUnsubscribes](https://help.bronto.com/bmp/reference/r_api_soap_readunsubscribes.html) is what you're looking for. There you can pass in a contactId to get a specific contact.

Comment: but then i have to figure out how to get the contactid . currently i would only have the users email address.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misusing the object property "status". If you look at this page, https://help.bronto.com/bmp/reference/r_api_soap_contactfilter.html, it shows all the the things status equals to. 
To be honest I think it would be better to use this the filter function to select the unsubscribed users and perform logic based on results of the filter.What does $contact->status == "unsub" return?
I mean there is always this https://help.bronto.com/bmp/reference/r_api_soap_readunsubscribes.html method for selecting unsubscribed users and then perform logic on users not found in this group.

```
        // print matching contact email addresses
         foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
         //$contact->status  always seems to have a status of active or null ??
          if($contact->status != 'unsub')
         {
            echo " <a href='' class='btn btn-primary'>Unsubscribe</a>";
         }
          else if($contact->status =='unsub')
         {
            echo " <a href=''>Subscribe</a>";
         }
           //print $contact->email . ': ' . $contact->status . "\n";
        }
```

I just noticed that your operators are not right. you have "=", shouldn't it be "=="?